# Mixing Java `ExecutorService` with Spring `TaskExecutor`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a piece of Java code that I previously used without Spring that looks like this:

```java
// `Callable` instead of `Runnable` because we need to throw exceptions
public MyTask extends Callable<Void> {
  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception { ... }
}

public class MyTasksRunner {

  private final ExecutorService executorService;

  ...

  public void run() throws Exception {
    List<MyTask> tasks = ...;
    var futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
    for (var future : futures) {
      // Rethrow any exceptions happened in the threads.
      future.get();
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm merging this code into a larger Spring Boot application that has async enabled. It configures a `TaskExecutor`, which doesn't have the same interface as `ExecutorService`. A `TaskExecutor` can only run `Runnable`s, not `Callable`s.

I can probably have a `TaskExecutor` bean for async Spring, and another `ExecutorService` bean for the `MyTasksRunner` code at the same time. But I wonder what options I have if I want to merge those:

- Can I tell Spring to use an `ExecutorService` for its async stuff?
- Can I convert my `Callable` code to use `Runnable`s instead, while still being able to propagate exceptions from the tasks?

I also thought about just making `MyTask` a Spring component and annotating it with `@Async`, but I don't really like that it makes the `MyTask*` code tied to Spring.

Comment: Did you intend to replace your `executorService` field to be of type `TaskExecutor` and inject that (or some flavor of that)?

Comment: @Savior The problem is `TaskExecutor` doesn't work with `Callable`s.

Comment: Right, but if it did, was that the solution you'd pursue?

Comment: @Savior Yes, if that would allow exception propagation.

Comment: If you're setting up the `TaskExecutor` through a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean, you can set your field (and the injection) to be of that explicit sub type. You can then use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`'s `getThreadPoolExecutor` to get the underlying `ThreadPoolExecutor` which is an `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can convert your `Callable` task to `Runnable` as I see you don't expect any return value. But with one condition - you cant throw Checked Exception however you may continue throwing Runtime Exception.

Also, yes you can define `Executor` bean as below to inject `ExecutorService`

```
@Bean
public Executor taskExecutor() {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    return executor;
}
```

If you dont define an Executor bean, Spring creates `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` and uses that.

Comment: Yeah, I converted the checked exceptions to `RuntimeException`s and now everything works.